# Recommended Set-Cookie Version used by web servers (0, 1, or 2)

Tags: http, tomcat, web, apache-httpcomponents

I was running into some issues with cookie management using Apache HTTP Components as a client talking to a web application running on a Tomcat server. Long story short, I found that it was due to the Set-Cookie headers using version 0, which by default causes HTTP Components to use a different logic flow and ignore host addresses without a domain suffix.
Although I can probably easily fix this by changing the cookie policy, I'm more curious about cookie versions in general. I can't seem to find very much information about which version "should" be used by web servers default these days. Tomcat appears to be defaulting to version 0 for compatibility. Shouldn't I configure it to use version 1 or 2, or is there a reason I should leave it? I'm not sure if there's any security/compatibility/functionality implications, or if it simply doesn't matter very much. I would imagine it's using version 0 to be compatible with old browsers, we aren't supporting old browsers anyways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cookie version attribute has been rendered obsolete by RFC 6265. You can configure HttpClient version 4.3 to use `Best_Match` policy or HttpClient version 4.4 to use `Standard` (RFC 6265 compliant) policy and disregard cookie versions altogether.